# Does google search index by IP address or domain name?

Tags: seo, google, google-search, heroku

I'm thinking of moving a mostly static website from homestead to heroku (using their free dyno plan to save monthly hosting costs). All else equal (e.g. let's say the content and files all remain as is), will simply moving from one host to another damage existing google search results?

The site has been around and hosted on homestead for about a decade and I want to avoid issues with google search indexation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google indexes by domain name, not by IP address. There is no SEO effect of changing the IP address your website is hosted from (unless the new IP is in a different country, or is an egregious repeat spam/malware offender which wouldn't be a problem with any reasonable hosting provider).

So as long as your content and files are identical, there is no SEO implication.